# Django override model get() method won't work on foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom model defined as following, with `get()` method override

```py
class CustomQuerySetManager(models.QuerySet):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Using custom manager')
        # some other logics here...
        return super(CustomQuerySetManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)


class CustomModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then I have two models defined as

```py
class Company(CustomModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class People(CustomModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

If I use `get()` directly like `People.objects.get(pk=1)` then it works, "Using custom manager" gets printed, but if I try to get the foreign key info, django still uses the `get()` method from the default manager, nothing gets printed and the rest of logic defined won't get executed, for example

```py
someone = People.objects.get(id=1)  # prints Using custom manager, custom logic executed
company_name = someone.company.name  # nothing gets printed, custom logic does not execute
```

Is the foreign key field in a model using a different manager even though the foreign key model is also using my custom model class? Is there a way to make my custom `get()` method work for all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As django doc says

> By default, Django uses an instance of the Model._base_manager manager
> class when accessing related objects (i.e. choice.question), not the
> _default_manager on the related object

See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access).

So you have to tell django model which manager to use as base manager, like this:

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        #django will use your custom "objects" manager as base_manager
        #or you may have different managers for base and default managers
        #if you define two managers with different names
        base_manager_name = 'objects' 
        abstract = True
```

But, please, pay attention that you do not filter away any results from base manager. Django doc says:

> This manager is used to access objects that are related to from some
> other model. In those situations, Django has to be able to see all the
> objects for the model it is fetching, so that anything which is
> referred to can be retrieved.

Therefore, do not override `get_queryset()` for this kind of managers.
See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#don-t-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass).